# Laravel DB::table increment not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, laravel, increment

I am trying to execute a statement in javascript:

```
function giveRespect(username, postnumber){
   alert('username');
   alert('postnumber');
   $.post('respect', {username: username, postnumber: postnumber});
}
```

**NOTE: the first alert correctly shows a username, example: 'Kori'.**

**NOTE: the second alert correctly shows a numeric value, example: 10.**

these examples might be weird, but now you have an idea in what form the data is.

It is hereby proven that data correctly flows into the method.

**The route ('/respect')**

```
Route::post('/respect', 'PostController@giveRespect');
```

*This route works* and has worked in the past. the giveRespect method is invoked when the giveRespect javascript function is called. this is proven due to the fact of a database increment statement being executed and indeed incrementing the number.

**The giveRespect method in PostController**

```
public function giveRespect(){
    DB::table('users')->increment('respect', 1, array('username' =>  Input::get('username')));   
    DB::table('post')->increment('respect', 1, array('id' =>  Input::get('postnumber')));
}
```

**The problem:**

The first line is executed correctly and indeed increments the respectcount,

The second, however, doesn't execute correctly and doesn't increment the respect count.

*Sidenotes*

- Tablenames are correct, i've checked, rechecked and checked again. 'users' is the first, 'post' is the second
- Columnnames are correct as well. 'respect' is the column that should be incremented

Answer (score 1):

I debugged this for an hour and
literally 5 minutes after posting this question i got it.. sorry guys, couldn't predict that.

**Answer**

The statement

DB::table('users')->increment('respect', 1, array('username' =>  Input::get('username')));

**does not do what i expected**. I expected the third parameter (the array) to be a where() method parameter, like: increment where 'username' IS < username >

**What does it actually do?**

the third parameter in the increment method allows you to specify a column that *will also be updated alongside the increment change*. Handy, but not in my case

**How did I reach the desired effect?**

```
public function giveRespect(){
    $user = user::where('username','=', Input::get('username'))->first();
    $user->increment('respect', 1);   
    $post = post::where('id', '=', Input::get('postnumber'))->first();
    $post->increment('respect', 1);
}
```

I first retreive the objects from the database with a where statement combined with Eloquent, and THEN i increment the respect counter

Comment: Be sure to accept your own answer as soon as it lets you!